# What is fflush exactly and what does it do?

Tags: c++, fflush, cstdio

I was reading http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/ and I was curious about what it means. According to the website it says:

> If the given stream was open for writing (or if it was open for updating and the last i/o operation was an output operation) any unwritten data in its output buffer is written to the file.

What does the output buffer to file mean?

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand. Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: What's actually unclear about the statements there? BTW, here's the [better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush) IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, could u post that in the answer

Comment: The data isn't immediately written to the physical file, but buffered up until a certain amount of data is available to store in the output device. That's done because the physical storing may be a costly operation, you don't want to do for every single byte written.

Comment: @Storm No that's not an answer, sorry ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, where is link

Comment: @Storm _'where is link'_ I don't get what you want??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, you had a link

Comment: @Storm Yes, I gave you this link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush, it's still there?!?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, no it not, you have this

Comment: 'What's actually unclear about the statements there? BTW, here's the better reference IMHO'

Comment: @Storm Sorry, I still don't get it? What link are you talking about? All links I gave on this question where in my 1st comment, and are still reachable from there!

Comment: that is what you have, @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: no it is not, it says IMHO

Comment: @Storm: You are not making any sense whatsoever. Please speak in complete sentences.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, There is no link in your first comment. I cant see one

Comment: @Storm Hover your mouse pointer over [**better reference**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush)! Facepalm ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, omg, sorry, didnt know u changed link to hyperlink XD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the need of fflush() and problems associated with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780908/understanding-the-need-of-fflush-and-problems-associated-with-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some streams buffer output data and do not write to the device immediately. `fflush` forces the contents of the stream's buffer, if there is one, to be written to the device and the buffer cleared.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that by default, `stdout` is line buffered (will flush after newlines), and `stderr` is unbuffered.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when data is intended to be written to a file, it is stored in a construct known as a "buffer". Once the buffer has reached a certain threshold, all the data stored in the buffer will be written out to the file at once.

Fflush empties the buffer and forces all changes to be written to the file. This is particularly useful when you are done writing to the file, since it is good practice to flush the buffer before closing the file (thereby making sure that all data has been successfully written to the file).

This goes for other types of filestreams too.

Comment: `fclose` flushes the buffer; calling `fflush` yourself before closing is redundant. I don't really think its a 'best practice'.

Comment: I got to agree with @ColonelThirtyTwo, it irks me when people do it, the same with checking for `NULL` before calling delete on a pointer...