# clrscr error in main program debug

Tags: c, debugging, fflush

I am receiving the error in function main for my `clrscr();` but I thought I had to clear when using `fflush(stdin);`?

I feel like I am missing something simple here but if anyone can shed some like I would appreciate it!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct person
{
        char name[10];
        int age;
};
typedef struct person NAME;
NAME  stud[10], temp[10];

void main()
{
     int no,i;

     void sort(int N);  /* Function declaration */

     clrscr();
     fflush(stdin);

     printf("Enter the number of students in the list\n");
     scanf("%d",&no);

     for(i = 0; i < no; i++)
     {
         printf("\nEnter the name of  person %d : ", i+1);
         fflush(stdin);
         gets(stud[i].name);

         printf("Enter the age of %d : ", i+1);
         scanf("%d",&stud[i].age);
         temp[i] = stud[i];
     }

     printf("\n*****************************\n");
     printf ("     Names before sorting     \n");
     /* Print the list of names before sorting */
     for(i=0;i<no;i++)
     {
            printf("%-10s\t%3d\n",temp[i].name,temp[i].age);
     }

     sort(no);       /* Function call */

     printf("\n*****************************\n");
     printf ("     Names after sorting     \n");
     printf("\n*****************************\n");
     /* Display the sorted names */
     for(i=0;i<no;i++)
     {
            printf("%-10s\t%3d\n",stud[i].name,stud[i].age);

     }
     printf("\n*****************************\n");
}          /* End of main() */

/* Function to sort the given names */
void sort(int N)
{
         int i,j;
         NAME temp;

         for(i = 0; i < N-1;i++)
         {
                for(j = i+1; j < N; j++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(stud[i].name,stud[j].name) > 0 )
                    {
                        temp    = stud[i];
                        stud[i] = stud[j];
                        stud[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
         }
}       /* end of sort() */
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your function prototype in the main function should be above main, I'm referring to `void sort(int N);`

Comment: per the standard, fflush(stdin) is undefined behaviour (even if some specific implementation allows it)   Flushing stdin is performed by the loop:  while( getchar() != EOF){;}

Comment: when the function prototype is buried within a function, the when the compiler encounters the actual function, it will assume the default types for parameters and return type (last I checked, that was all 'int') which probably is not what you want.  Suggest placing function prototypes after the #include header files and before any actual function declarations

Comment: the conio.h file is not portable.  strongly suggest not using it.  use 'system( "cls" );' instead of clrscr().

Comment: there are a number of problems with the code:  1) main is declared as 'int main( void ) or 'int main( int argc, char* argv[])  any other form is invalid  2) the definition of 'temp inside the sort() function shadows the global definition of temp, so the actual data will not be sorted.

Comment: do not typedef struct definitions.   the typedef'ing clutters the code, makes it harder for humans to read, often is mis-leading, and clutters the compiler name space.   So everywhere in the code that 'NAME' is used, replace with 'struct person'

Comment: always check (not the parameters)the returned value from scanf(), and family of function, to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: do not use 'gets()' as it is removed from the language standard, is depreciated, is full of security holes, can easily overrun the input buffer.  Suggest using: 'fgets()'

Comment: @user3629249 : as OP uses conio.h, I assume the program is compiled with MSVC which supports using fflush to cleanup input streams even if it is not standard.

Comment: for robust code, after inputting the 'age', check that it is a positive number and check for a reasonable upper limits, for instance 100.

Comment: this line: 'temp[i] = stud[i];' will not copy the struct entry.  Suggest: memcpy( &temp[i], &stud[i], sizeof(struct person) );

Comment: this line: 'gets(stud[i].name);' will input a string (any length)(including the newline), append a '\0' at the end.   So, on DOS/Windows, the max usable name (without buffer overflow) is 7 characters.  on other OSs, the max usable name (without buffer overflow) is 8 characters.   Is 7 or 8 characters enough?  my name: 'Richard', would have good chance of overflowing the buffer.   Also, when displaying/sorting, etc the array of struct person, you (probably) do not want to be sorting a newline.  Therefore, 1) make the field significantly longer, 2) replace the newline with a '\0' character

Comment: the sort() function will fail because (for instance) temp = stud[i] will not copy the whole struct.  suggest using:  memcpy( &temp, &stud[i], sizeof(struct person) );

Comment: please use spaces when indenting (I like 4 spaces as that shows nicely, even with variable width fonts)  because every decent editor/wordprocessor can/will set the tab width or tab stops differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put the function prototype `void sort(int N);` outside `main()`
2. You don't have (but you may) execute `clrscr()` before `fflush(stdin)`. In this case contents of your screen (which you want to clear) have nothing to do with `stdin`.

You can read more about `fflush()` and the motivation to use it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780908/understanding-the-need-of-fflush-and-problems-associated-with-it).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you get a compilation error. It is caused by the line above the one where you see the error.

As suggested by @Catalyst, it is caused here by the line

```
void sort(int N);  /* Function declaration */`
```

because C does not allow functions to be declared locally inside other functions (and `main` **is** a function).

You can simply fix it that way :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct person
{
        char name[10];
        int age;
};
typedef struct person NAME;
NAME  stud[10], temp[10];

void sort(int N);  /* Function declaration */


int main()    // void main is incorrect
{
     int no,i;

     clrscr();
     fflush(stdin);
...
```

Note also the `int main()` instead of `void main()`. It is harmless on Windows, but is still incorrect.

Comment: Ok I moved it that was dumb haha. Still getting the same error. clrscr(); is highlighted with in function mainas the error.